# Django get_or_create ValueError

Tags: django, django-models

Trying to add rows from a DataFrame into Django model.

**models.py**:

```
class CreditIndex_TEST(models.Model):
    loanBook = models.ForeignKey(LoanBooks, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    run_date = models.DateField()
    index_date = models.DateField()
    index_CD = models.IntegerField()
    Index_value = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields= ['loanBook','run_date','index_date','index_CD'], name='unique_CreditIndexPair')
            ]
```

**views.py**:

```
for index, row in tempDf.iterrows():
            obj, created = CreditIndex_TEST.objects.get_or_create(
                loanBook=dbname,
                run_date= run_date,
                index_date=row['Date'],
                index_CD=1,
                Index_value=row['CreditIndex_CD1']
            )
```

**ERROR:**:

```
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Botswana_TU'.
```

I don't understand why I am being asked to specify `id`. The record I am trying to add to the model does not exist and therefore Django should create it and assign `id`, not expect it from me?

**EDIT** (full traceback):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/gunthermarais/credit-risk/django/RiskLab/Provisions/views.py", line 48, in macroGUI
    Index_value=row['CreditIndex_CD1']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 575, in update_or_create
    obj = self.select_for_update().get(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 404, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 904, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 923, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1350, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1381, in _add_q
    check_filterable=check_filterable,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1311, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1165, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_lookups.py", line 115, in get_prep_lookup
    self.rhs = target_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1776, in get_prep_value
    ) from e
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Botswana_TU'.
```

Comment: Do you have any signals connected to `CreditIndex_TEST` model?

Comment: Not that I know of. I don't know what ```signals``` are if that answers your question.

Comment: Please provide the full trace

Comment: @gmarais [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/) are signals. Try to search for `sender=CreditIndex_TEST` in your code. Also, check if `dbname` is not equal `Botswana_TU` or a string in general.

Comment: @Charnel, thanks I did research signals before answering you and I confirm that I do not have signals in my code. Also, ```dbname``` is a variable, in this case the value was ```Botswana_TU```

Comment: @gmarais ok, so here is at least one problem - you're trying to pass string value to `loanBook` field which is foreign key, that is wrong. Perhaps you wanted to get `LoanBooks` record by name (Botswana_TU) and then pass it's ID as `dbname` value?

Comment: Correct, I figure this out a few hours ago. I was trying to assign a ```string``` to the foreignkey ```loanBook```. Nice catch and thanks for sticking with me